# Module object not callable error when using Boto3 with DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to insert an item into my DynamoDB using the Python SDK (I'm not familiar with Python too much). I'm also using MQTT to retrieve some data. Currently the MQTT part works fine (I have some hard coded values for now so I can focus on getting the AWS functionality working)

I'm also using an AWS Educate account so need to pass in my access keys etc (which I've removed from the code for posting here). The code right now is:

```
from pprint import pprint
import boto3
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace

broker = "35.173.177.9"        

#MQTT function
def onMessage(client, userdata, message):
    print("Message recieved: ", str(message.payload.decode("utf-8", "ignore")))

    movie_resp = putItem(1000, "1.1.1.1", "Pi", "06/01/21")

    print("Put item succeeded:")

    pprint(movie_resp, sort_dicts=False)

def putItem(id, ip, deviceName, clickDate, dynamodb=None):
    session = boto3.session(
    aws_access_key_id="",
    aws_secret_access_key="",
    aws_session_token="",
    region_name='us-west-1'
    )

   if not dynamodb:
      dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb')

   table = dynamodb.Table('piData')

   response = table.put_item(
   Item={
        'ip': ip,
        'id': id,
        'deviceName': deviceName,
        'clickDate': clickDate
    }
   )

   return response

#MQTT code below
client = paho.Client("awsUbuntuEC2")
client.on_message = onMessage
client.connect(broker)
client.subscribe("jsonData")
client.loop_forever()
```

When running the code I get:

```
"TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"
```

on line

```
session = boto3.session(
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `boto3.session` is a module.  There is a class inside that module named `Session`, which is presumably what you want.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks, that seems to have worked. Just getting an AccessDeniedException on the PutItem operation now but I assume that's something to do with permissions somewhere. Cheers for the help

Edit: Doesn't matter, I had my region set wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change from session = boto3.session to :
session = boto3.**Session** (Capital S in session )

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `from boto3 import Session` at the headers and try running the file again, please.